# Error When Calling Function

Tags: php, bots

I searched forever trying to find an answer, but was ultimately stumped. I've been writing code to allow multiple bots to connect to a chat box. I wrote all the main code and checked it over to make sure it was all okay. Then when I got to calling the function needed to make it work, it gave me an error saying:

> Notice: Undefined variable: ip in C:\wamp\www\BotRaid.php on line 40

And also an error saying:

> Fatal Error: Cannot access empty property in C:\wamp\www\BotRaid.php
>   on line 40

( Also a screenshot here: http://prntscr.com/ckz55 )

```
<?php

    date_default_timezone_set("UCT");
    declare(ticks=1);
    set_time_limit(0);

    class BotRaid
    {
        public $ip="174.36.242.26";
        public $port=10038;
        public $soc = null;
        public $packet = array();

        ##############################
        #   You can edit below this  #
        ##############################
        public $roomid="155470742";
        public $userid = "606657406";
        public $k = "2485599605";

        public $name="";
        public $avatar=;
        public $homepage="";
        ##############################
        #        Stop editing        #
        ##############################

        public function retry()
        {
            $this->connect($this->$ip,$this->$port); //Line 40, where I'm getting the error now.
            $this->join($this->$roomid);

            while($this->read()!="DIED");
        }

        public function connect($ip, $port)
        {
            if($this->$soc!=null) socket_close($this->$soc);
            $soc = socket_create(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,SOL_TCP);
            if(!$this->$soc)$this->port();
            if(!socket_connect($this->$soc,$this->$ip,$this->$port))$this->port();
        }

        public function port()
        {
            $this->$port++;
            if($this->$port>10038) $this->$port=10038;
            $this->retry();
        }

        public function join($roomid)
        {
            $this->send('<y m="1" />');
            $this->read();
            $this->send('<j2 q="1" y="'.$this->$packet['y']['i'].'" k="'.$this->$k.'" k3="0" z="12" p="0" c"'.$roomid.'" f="0" u="'.$this->$userid.'" d0="0" n="'.$this->$name.'" a="'.$this->$avatar.'" h="'.$this->$homepage.'" v="0" />');
            $this->port();
            $this->$roomid;
        }

        public function send($msg)
        {
            echo "\n Successfully connected.";
            socket_write($this->$soc, $this->$msg."\0", strlen($this->$msg)+1);
        }

        public function read($parse=true)
        {
            $res = rtrim(socket_read($this->$soc, 4096));
            echo "\nSuccessfully connected.";
            if(strpos(strtolower($res), "Failed"))$this->port();
            if(!$res) return "DIED";
            $this->lastPacket = $res;
            if($res{strlen($res)-1}!='>') {$res.=$this->read(false);}
            if($parse)$this->parse($res);
            return $res;
        }

        public function parse($packer)
        {
            $packet=str_replace('+','@più@',str_replace(' ="',' @=@"',$packet));
            if(substr_count($packet,'>')>1) $packet = explode('/>',$packet);
            foreach((Array)$packet as $p) {
                $p = trim($p);
                if(strlen($p)<5) return;
                $type = trim(strtolower(substr($p,1,strpos($p.' ',' '))));
                $p = trim(str_replace("<$type",'',str_replace('/>','',$p)));
                parse_str(str_replace('"','',str_replace('" ','&',str_replace('="','=',str_replace('&','__38',$p)))),$this->packet[$type]);
                foreach($this->packet[$type] as $k=>$v) {
                    $this->packet[$type][$k] = str_replace('@più@','+',str_replace('@=@','=',str_replace('__38','&',$v)));
                }
            }   
        }
    }

    $bot = new BotRaid; //This is where I had the error originally
    $bot->retry();

?>
```

Line 40 is below the "Stop Editing" line. Anyone have any suggestions? Or perhaps need me to clear some things up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are accessing the properties of the class incorrectly.

The line:

```
$this->connect($this->$ip,$this->$port);
```

Should be:

```
$this->connect($this->ip, $this->port);
```

Since there was no local variable called `$ip`, your expression was evaluating to `$this->` when trying to access the property since PHP lets you access properties and functions using variables.

For example, this would work:

```
$ip = 'ip';
$theIp = $this->$ip; // evaluates to $this->ip

// or a function call
$method = 'someFunction';
$value  = $this->$method(); // evaluates to $this->someFunction();
```

You will have to change all the occurrences of `$this->$foo` with `$this->foo` since you used that notation throughout the class.

As noted in the comment by @Aatch, see the docs on [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) for further explanation.  But that is what you were running into accidentally.

Comment: Yet another gotcha for PHP, variable variables!

Comment: Aah, thank you. I have changed everything that needed to be changed. Yet, I still get one more error. As noted here: http://prntscr.com/ckzg8 . Line 49 being "$soc = socket_create(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,SOL_TCP);"

Comment: Is it just that `if($this->$soc!=null) socket_close($this->$soc);` still hasn't been changed to `if($this->soc!=null) socket_close($this->soc);`?  Line 49 shouldn't cause undefined variable $soc since you are assigning to it.

Comment: Ah bummer, in that case you are SOL; the version of PHP you are running on was compiled without socket support, so the function `socket_create` does not exist in your PHP build and you will not be able to use it.  See [Sockets - Installation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/sockets.installation.php) for explanation.

Comment: I wasted a good couple hours of my life then. Oh well, it happens. I really appreciate your help. I'll see if I can find someone with socket support to at least test if for me.

Comment: Are you running this on a hosted server or is it PHP you are using on your own machine? You may be able to ask your host to enable it, but even so, your account most likely doesn't have the proper permissions within the OS to bind to a port for listening.  Only super users can do this.  Your best bet may be to install XAMPP or something so you can test locally.

Comment: Nevermind, ignore that last comment, you aren't trying to bind to a port for listening, only trying to connect.  You shouldn't have any issues running that on an unprivileged account.  Nothing about that code looks too tailored to `sockets`, you may be able to convert it to use `fsockopen` and `fread`, `fwrite`.  Those functions will be available to all PHP versions.

Comment: I was running it locally to begin with, then tested it on my host and also got an error. How would I convert it over to something other than sockets? I write in Python mainly, sorry for the trouble.

Comment: Put simply, you would change the `socket_create` to be `$soc = fsockopen($host, $port);` and then you would change your `read()` and `write()` to use `fgets` and `fwrite` respectively instead of `socket_read` and `socket_write`.  The man page for [fsockopen](http://php.net/fsockopen) shows a simple example that sends an HTTP request and reads the response.  For you it is similar except your connection stays open until closed. But basically you read and write to it on demand.

Comment: Thank you. That's all I'm going to ask of you at this time. I think I can get the rest on my own. I appreciate the feedback.

Comment: You're welcome, feel free to contact me via the form from the site in my SO profile if you have other questions.  Sounds like interesting stuff you are doing, this used to be what I spent a lot of my time coding.